# Escape special characters between the start of a word and a colon using Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm trying to escape 2 special characters, which are `*` and `?` in a string if they appear **between the start of a word and a colon.** For example:

```
Input: creator*:Joh*n url:*google*
Output: creator\*:Joh*n url:*google*
```

And here is my JavaScript code:

```
var str   = 'creator*:Joh*n url:*google*';
var regex = /\b([\w.]*)([\*\?]+)([\w.]*:)/g;
str = str.replace(regex, "$1\\$2$3");
alert(str);
```

It works as I expected. However, there are 2 problems:

**Problem 1:** It doesn't work if `*` is at the beginning of the word.

```
Input: *creator:Joh*n url:*google*
Output: *creator:Joh*n url:*google*
Expected result: \*creator:Joh*n url:*google*
```

**Problem 2:** It doesn't work if there are more than one `*`.

```
Input: cre*ato*r:Joh*n url:*google*
Output: cre*ato\*r:Joh*n url:*google*
Expected result: cre\*ato\*r:Joh*n url:*google*
```

What's wrong with my pattern? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do this in the following way

```js
function replace(str){
    return str.replace(/([*?])(?=[^\s]*:)/g, '\\$1');
}


console.log(replace('creator*:John url:*google*'));
console.log(replace('*creator:John url:*google*'));
console.log(replace('cre*ato*r:John url:*google*'));
console.log(replace('creator*:John url:*google* author:Alice'));
```

see the [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/m5ENz8/2)

Comment: should be \ not /

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but if we change to `Joh*n`, it will escape the `*` too, which I don't want to. Please look at my updated code :)

Comment: Thank you so much, it works! Because I want to match both `*` and `?`, please update your pattern to `([\*\?])(?=[^\s]*:)` and the replacement to `\\$1` :D